# J3D - How to use a UV mapping of an object to convert 2D coordinates to 3D ones

Tags: java, 3d, blender, java-3d, uv-mapping

I am currently working on trying to convert 2D coordinates to 3D ones.
Basically, I have the texture in 2D and I would like to be able to show on a 3D object, having the same texture applied to it, where I am pointing at.

Let's say I have the 2D texture of the world. I would like to be able to know, given U,V coordinates on the texture, to get the X,Y,Z coordinates on a sphere having the same texture applied to it.

I am using J3D and now I am working with blender and figure out what is the best way to tackle this problem.

Any idea?

**EDIT**:

Here is a graphical idea of what I am trying to achieve: [image]

You get (X,Y) coordinates of a point on a 2D texture and, thanks to some function, get and visualize where it would be if it was placed on a 3D object (I define both the mapping and the object itself).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a J3D user not I've used it ever before, I've used these in Blender and OpenGL, so I think I can attempt this question.

I think you are having some trouble understanding texturing in 3D. **You will not generate the vertices from the UV coordinates,** you will use the UV coordinates (which I call `texCoords` for clarity) on the vertices to apply the textures to them. If you don't know how to do UV mapping in blender, you can watch my video [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POWq9aeDLls)

Then you have some steps as specified in [this](http://www.vrupl.evl.uic.edu/oldsite/VRLabAcc/about_vrlab/java3d/lesson05/index.html) tutorial.

First, you need to create a polygon. Hoping that you know it already, skipping it here. Then set the texture coordinates onto that polygon like this.

```
polygon1.setTextureCoordinate (0, new Point2f(u1, v1));
polygon1.setTextureCoordinate (1, new Point2f(u2, v2)); 
polygon1.setTextureCoordinate (2, new Point2f(u3, v3));
polygon1.setTextureCoordinate (3, new Point2f(u4, v4));
```

Assuming that the coordinates are in UV (Some also call them ST).

Then you load the texture image using the `TextureLoader` class.

```
Texture texImage = new TextureLoader("brick.jpg", this).getTexture();
```

Then set it on the `appearance` using it's `setTexture()` method. And that's it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try to follow your suggestions, thanks. But, just to clarify, I need to be able to send X,Y coordinates to a function (coordinates related to a 2D image) and it returns X,Y,Z coordinates, which represent the location of that point on the texture when applied to the object.

Basically, I am looking for a way to create a 2D matrix returning 3D coordinates. Let's say I click on the city of London (in the 2D image), I should be able to have a small pointer in the 3D object, where London is located on that object.

Comment: @N3sh Could you clarify a bit more? Do you want to be able to select an object in the 3d space by clicking on its texture or what?